# Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create common header and footer pages that are included on several html pages.

I'd like to use javascript. Is there a way to do this using only html and JavaScript?

I want to load a header and footer page within another html page.

Comment: You are looking for ajax... $('.myElement).load('urltopage.html'); this will load urltopage.html's content in .myElement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8592403/896341

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to jQuery or CSS?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Place this code in `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and put this code in `header.html` and `footer.html`, at the same location as `index.html`

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">click here for google</a>
```

Now, when you visit `index.html`, you should be able to click the link tags.

Comment: Yes. all page should have these page structure

Comment: Yes and we are just calling the content from other html files

Comment: that means the other 2 html pages header.html and footer.html 
that pages contain the contents..

Comment: Does this load fast enough that the user doesn't see a blip on every page load?  I was wondering whether it would be necessary to store the html in a cookie or local storage for quicker reloading.

Comment: load or other function that import or use a `local file` not work in new version of Google Chrome or IE, reason: security!

Comment: Couple issues with this approach. It will not work on chrome when you are working locally. You have to put it on local server. The other issue it will load header and footer after it renders all html. So that there will be a delay to load header and footers. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25288597] (More information)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how people can even breathe without jQuery. Or is there a `.breathe(in)` and `.breathe(out)` already? Any scripting language is pure overkill here.

Comment: I keep getting `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` when I run in chrome

Comment: It is required to run the code in server. Which means url needs to be like "http://.....".

Comment: Patriotic is right, it must run under a web server.

Comment: You can see [my answer below using HTML5 Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46515280/7120290)

Comment: The cross origin error will only be a problem locally because you access the file through file:// protocol. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578692/4266296). You can either test locally with Firefox, upload the file(s) to a server or run a web server locally like other comments already mentioned.

Comment: If the footer / header has a lot of links, what will be the impact of using this technique on seo ?

Comment: the only downside is that the links and stuff will be loaded in the `<body>` and not in the `<header>`

Comment: Guys who are having trouble making it work, Make sure:
1) you are running a local server.
2) you are not using defer/async for Jquery script.

Comment: Thanks for the above method, Is this going to work if we use bootstrap on the page included and also on the home page?

Comment: Is this an acceptable answer or this approach with the local file has been stopped by chrome as mentioned in the comments?

Answer (score 57):

I add common parts as header and footer using **Server Side Includes**. No HTML and no JavaScript is needed. Instead, the webserver automatically adds the included code before doing anything else.

Just add the following line where you want to include your file:

```
<!--#include file="include_head.html" -->
```

Comment: i like this old-fashioned way.  In fact, it doesn't seem to have a whole lot benefits using script to do such a simple action.

Comment: In fact, including files using a script has major disadvantages: It hinders performance as the client needs to download the main page, load the DOM, run the script and only then can download the included files, which needs an additional server request per included file. Including files using Server Side Includes serves all elements during the first server request, there's no client action needed.

Comment: SSI requires using a file extension of: `.shtml`, `.stm`, `.shtm`. It works in Apache, LiteSpeed, nginx, lighttpd and IIS.

Comment: @ubershmekel As you said, the relevant webservers support SSI. The file extension is not limited to `.shtml`, `.stm` and `.shtm`: On IIS, all parsed files may contain SSI, e.g. `.aspx`. If working with PHP, you need to use the PHP `include` or `virtual` command instead to achieve the same result.

Comment: *Which* web server?

Comment: @php_nub_qq see ubershmekel's comment above for some webserver names. In short: All relevant webservers support SSI.

Comment: @TheConspiracy I was implying that perhaps you don't have a web-server, or use one that doesn't - such as github pages - in which case you're out of luck :P

Answer (score 41):

Must you use html file structure with JavaScript?  Have you considered using PHP instead so that you can use simple PHP include object?

If you convert the file names of your .html pages to .php - then at the top of each of your .php pages you can use one line of code to include the content from your header.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
```

Do the same in the footer of each page to include the content from your footer.php file

```
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

No JavaScript / Jquery or additional included files required.

NB You could also convert your .html files to .php files using the following in your .htaccess file

```
# re-write html to php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# re-write no extension to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Justin808 - the OP mentions nothing about a local hosted installation, so I presumed he was talking about server based files.

Comment: @Sol However the OP DID specifically mention wanting to use Javascript, so your answer is off-topic. Full-stack web development is quickly moving away from using PHP at all, Node.js provides all of the equivalent functionality and requires only Javascript to be used. 

TL;DR please answer questions as asked. The OP wanted a JS solution, so it's inappropriate to give him a solution PHP, Ruby, Python, C++, or any other language.

Answer (score 14):

You could also put: (load_essentials.js:)

```js
document.getElementById("myHead").innerHTML =
 "<span id='headerText'>Title</span>"
 + "<span id='headerSubtext'>Subtitle</span>";
document.getElementById("myNav").innerHTML =
 "<ul id='navLinks'>"
 + "<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>"
 + "<li><a href='about.html'>About</a>"
 + "<li><a href='donate.html'>Donate</a></li>"
 + "</ul>";
document.getElementById("myFooter").innerHTML =
 "<p id='copyright'>Copyright &copy; " + new Date().getFullYear() + " You. All"
 + " rights reserved.</p>"
 + "<p id='credits'>Layout by You</p>"
 + "<p id='contact'><a href='mailto:you@you.com'>Contact Us</a> / "
 + "<a href='mailto:you@you.com'>Report a problem.</a></p>";
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<header id="myHead"></header>
<nav id="myNav"></nav>
Content
<footer id="myFooter"></footer>

<script src="load_essentials.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can use ` `  for multiple lines

Answer (score 13):

The question asks about using **only HTML and JavaScript**. The problem is that a second request to the server using JavaScript or even jQuery (requesting the extra `header.html` "later") is:

**Slow!**

So, this is unacceptable in a production environment. The way to go is to include only one `.js` file and serve your HTML template **using only this .js file**. So, step 1, in your HTML you can have:

```
<header id="app-header"></header>
<script async src="header.js"></script>
```

And then, step 2, put your template in your `header.js`. Use backticks for this HTML string:

```
let appHeader = `
    <nav>
       /*navigation or other html content here*/
    </nav>
`;
document.getElementById("app-header").innerHTML = appHeader;
```

This has also the benefit, that you can change the content of your template **dynamically** if you need, because it is JavaScript!
Also, try `defer` (or even nothing) insted of async, but it may seem slower to the user - this depends on your other content, so just try. Just, don't forget to put the `script` after the `header`.

**Explanation about speed**

In the HTTP/2 world, the web server "undestands" what additional files (.css, .js, etc) should be sent along with a specific `.html`, and sends them altogether in the initial response. But, if in your "original" `.html` you do not have this `header.html` file imported (because you intend to call it later with a script), it won't be sent initially. So, when your JavaScript/jQuery requests it (this will happen much later, when HTML and your JavaScript will get "interpreted"), your browser will send a second request to the server, wait for the answer, and then do its stuff... That's why this is slow. You can validate this, using any browser's developer tools, watching the `header.html` coming much later.

So, as a general advice (there are a lot of exceptions of course), import all your additional files in your original `.html` (or `php`) file if you care about speed. Use `defer` or `async` if needed. **Do not import any files later** using JavaScript.

Answer (score 11):

I tried this:
Create a file **header.html** like

```
<!-- Meta -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<title>Your application</title>
```

Now include **header.html** in your HTML pages like:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
   <script> 
     $(function(){ $("head").load("header.html") });
   </script>
</head>
```

Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Nice solution, but I think this would load the jquery framework twice, once for the initial page load, and secondly when the .load() method executes - since the target page also contains jquery.

Answer (score 6):

I've been working in C#/Razor and since I don't have IIS setup on my home laptop I looked for a javascript solution to load in views while creating static markup for our project.

I stumbled upon a website explaining methods of "ditching jquery," it demonstrates a method on the site does exactly what you're after in plain Jane javascript (*reference link at the bottom of post*). Be sure to investigate any security vulnerabilities and compatibility issues if you intend to use this in production. I am not, so I never looked into it myself.

**JS Function**

```
var getURL = function (url, success, error) {
    if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) return;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status !== 200) {
                if (error && typeof error === 'function') {
                    error(request.responseText, request);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (success && typeof success === 'function') {
                success(request.responseText, request);
            }
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.send();
};
```

**Get the content**

```
getURL(
    '/views/header.html',
    function (data) {
        var el = document.createElement(el);
        el.innerHTML = data;
        var fetch = el.querySelector('#new-header');
        var embed = document.querySelector('#header');
        if (!fetch || !embed) return;
        embed.innerHTML = fetch.innerHTML;

    }
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- This element will be replaced with #new-header -->
<div id="header"></div>
```

**views/header.html**

```
<!-- This element will replace #header -->
<header id="new-header"></header>
```

The source is not my own, I'm merely referencing it as it's a good vanilla javascript solution to the OP. Original code lives here: http://gomakethings.com/ditching-jquery#get-html-from-another-page

Answer (score 4):

I think, answers to this question are too old... currently some desktop and mobile browsers support **HTML Templates** for doing this.

I've built a little example:

**Tested OK** in Chrome 61.0, Opera 48.0, Opera Neon 1.0, Android Browser 6.0, Chrome Mobile 61.0 and Adblocker Browser 54.0
**Tested KO** in Safari 10.1, Firefox 56.0, Edge 38.14 and IE 11

More compatibility info in [canisue.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports)

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML Template Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="import" href="autoload-template.html">
</head>
<body>

<div class="template-container">1</div>
<div class="template-container">2</div>
<div class="template-container">3</div>
<div class="template-container">4</div>
<div class="template-container">5</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**`autoload-template.html`**

```
<span id="template-content">
    Template Hello World!
</span>

<script>
    var me = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    var post = me.querySelector( '#template-content' );

    var container = document.querySelectorAll( '.template-container' );

    //alert( container.length );
    for(i=0; i<container.length ; i++) {
        container[i].appendChild( post.cloneNode( true ) );
    }
</script>
```

**`styles.css`**

```css
#template-content {
    color: red;
}

.template-container {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: blue;
}
```

Your can get more examples in this [HTML5 Rocks post](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

Comment: HTML Imports is now deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Aloha from 2018. Unfortunately, I don't have anything cool or futuristic to share with you.

I did however want to point out to those who have commented that the jQuery `load()` method isn't working in the present are probably trying to use the method with local files without running a local web server. Doing so will throw the above mentioned "cross origin" error, which specifies that cross origin requests such as that made by the load method are only supported for protocol schemes like `http`, `data`, or  `https`. (I'm assuming that you're not making an actual cross-origin request, i.e the header.html file is actually on the same domain as the page you're requesting it from)

So, if the accepted answer above isn't working for you, please make sure you're running a web server. The quickest and simplest way to do that if you're in a rush (and using a Mac, which has Python pre-installed) would be to spin up a simple Python http server. You can see how easy it is to do that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lE6Y6M9xPLw).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Using a web server defeats the point though, at least for me the reason to use Javascript only is to develop it easier.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick setup with plain javascript and because not answered yet, you could also use a `.js` file to store your redundant pieces *(templates)*  of HTML inside a variable and insert it through `innerHTML`.

**[backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/usage-of-the-backtick-character-in-javascript)** are here the ***make it easy part*** this answer is about.
*(you will also want to follow the link on that backticks SO Q/A if you read & test that answer)*.

example for a navbar that remains the same on each page :

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <a href="/" class="here"><img src="image.png" alt="Home"/></a>
    <a href="/about.html" >About</a>      
    <a href="/services.html" >Services</a>          
    <a href="/pricing.html" >Pricing</a>    
    <a href="/contact.html" >Contact Us</a>
</nav>
```

You can keep inside your HTMl :

```
<nav role="navigation"></nav>
```

and set inside  **`nav.js`** file the content of `<nav>` as a variable in between backticks:

```
const nav= `
    <a href="/" class="here"><img src="image.png" alt="Home"/></a>
    <a href="/about.html" >About</a>      
    <a href="/services.html" >Services</a>          
    <a href="/pricing.html" >Pricing</a>    
    <a href="/contact.html" >Contact Us</a>
` ;
```

Now you have a small file from which you can retrieve a variable containing HTML. It looks very similar to include.php and can easily be updated without messing it up *(what's inside the backticks)*.

You can now link that file like any other javascript file and  innerHTML the var `nav` inside `<nav role="navigation"></nav>` via

```
let barnav = document.querySelector('nav[role="navigation"]');
    barnav.innerHTML = nav;
```

If you add or remove pages, you only have to update once `nav.js`

basic HTML page can be :

```js
// code standing inside nav.js for easy edit
const nav = `
    <a href="/" class="here"><img src="image.png" alt="Home"/></a>
    <a href="/about.html" >About</a>      
    <a href="/services.html" >Services</a>          
    <a href="/pricing.html" >Pricing</a>    
    <a href="/contact.html" >Contact Us</a>
`;
```

```css
nav[role="navigation"] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <!-- update title   if not home page -->
  <meta name="description" content=" HTML5 ">
  <meta name="author" content="MasterOfMyComputer">
  <script src="nav.js"></script>
  <!-- load an html template through a variable -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <nav role="navigation">
    <!-- it will be loaded here -->
  </nav>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <!-- update h1 if not home page -->

  <script>
    // this part can also be part of nav.js 
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      let barnav = document.querySelector('nav[role="navigation"]');
      barnav.innerHTML = nav;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This quick example works & can be copy/paste then edited to change variable names and variable HTML content.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to load scripts and links into the header. 
I'll be adding it one of the examples above...

```
<!--load_essentials.js-->
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />');
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />');
document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');

document.getElementById("myHead").innerHTML =
"<span id='headerText'>Title</span>"
+ "<span id='headerSubtext'>Subtitle</span>";
document.getElementById("myNav").innerHTML =
"<ul id='navLinks'>"
+ "<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>"
+ "<li><a href='about.html'>About</a>"
+ "<li><a href='donate.html'>Donate</a></li>"
+ "</ul>";
document.getElementById("myFooter").innerHTML =
"<p id='copyright'>Copyright &copy; " + new Date().getFullYear() + " You. All"
+ " rights reserved.</p>"
+ "<p id='credits'>Layout by You</p>"
+ "<p id='contact'><a href='mailto:you@you.com'>Contact Us</a> / "
+ "<a href='mailto:you@you.com'>Report a problem.</a></p>";

<!--HTML-->
<header id="myHead"></header>
<nav id="myNav"></nav>
Content
<footer id="myFooter"></footer>

<script src="load_essentials.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach made available since this question was first asked is to use reactrb-express (see http://reactrb.org)  This will let you script in ruby on the client side, replacing your html code with react components written in ruby.

Comment: op asked only using html and javascript but you take him to use ruby.. :D lol but cool tool man..

Comment: I took the spirit of the question to be - without serverside templating languages.  it all compiles down to Javascript so I believe it meets the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax
main.js

```
fetch("./includes/header.html")
    .then(response => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
        document.querySelector("header").innerHTML = data;
    });

fetch("./includes/footer.html")
    .then(response => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
        document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML = data;
    });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Liks</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <main></main>
        <footer></footer>
        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use object tag of HTML with out use of JavaScript.

```
<object data="header.html" type="text/html" height="auto"></object>
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Create a file called header.js and paste following code:
`$(function(){ $("#header").html(`



........`);  });`

Step 2: Add  at proper place as you seem fit

Step 3: Add following code before ending of body tag:

```
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="header.js"></script>
```

Do same steps for footer or sidebar.

Comment: jQuery 3.2.1 is seven years old and contains some security problems. That version should no longer be used in any project. Also, please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights

Answer (score -2):

Credits : W3 Schools [How to Include HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Save the HTML you want to include in an .html file:

**Content.html**

```
<a href="howto_google_maps.asp">Google Maps</a><br>
<a href="howto_css_animate_buttons.asp">Animated Buttons</a><br>
<a href="howto_css_modals.asp">Modal Boxes</a><br>
<a href="howto_js_animate.asp">Animations</a><br>
<a href="howto_js_progressbar.asp">Progress Bars</a><br>
<a href="howto_css_dropdown.asp">Hover Dropdowns</a><br>
<a href="howto_js_dropdown.asp">Click Dropdowns</a><br>
<a href="howto_css_table_responsive.asp">Responsive Tables</a><br>
```

**Include the HTML**

Including HTML is done by using a **w3-include-html** attribute:

**Example**

```
    <div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
```

**Add the JavaScript**

HTML includes are done by JavaScript.

```
    <script>
    function includeHTML() {
      var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
      /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
      z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
      for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        if (file) {
          /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
              if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
              if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
              /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
              elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
              includeHTML();
            }
          } 
          xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
          xhttp.send();
          /*exit the function:*/
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Call includeHTML() at the bottom of the page:

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
};
</script>
<body>

<div w3-include-html="h1.html"></div> 
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get white blank page when I test index.html after that

Comment: At least credit your [source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Comment: (1) it still needs to be run on a server (2) it does not work well with css styling, so no fancy navigation menus.