# $http.get does not return anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My factory method:

```
angular.module('ymusica').factory('Albums', ['$http', function($http) {
return {
    query: function(term) {
        return $http.get('/api/album', { params: { q: term } });
    }
 };
}]);
```

IT does not work, means it not return anything. If my api path is incorrect then how can i correct it. Here i use rx.js, rx.time.js, rx.coincidence and typeahead.js. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks...

Console error:
[image]

Here is my controller.js:

```
angular.module('ymusica').controller('AlbumSearch', ['$scope', 'Albums', 'Artists', '$q', function($scope, albums, artists, $q) {

$scope.albums = [];
$scope.artists = [];

var watchToObservable = function(scope, expression) {
    var observable = new Rx.Subject();

    scope.$watch(expression, observable.onNext.bind(observable));

    return observable;
}

var functionToObservable = function(scope, name) {

    var observable = new Rx.Subject();

    scope[name] = function(value) {
        observable.onNext(value);
    };

    return observable;
}

var terms = functionToObservable($scope, 'searchMusic');

terms.sample(250)
    .select(function(term) {
        var promise = $q.all([albums.query(term), artists.query(term)]);
        return Rx.promiseToObservable(promise)
    })
    .switchLatest()
    .select(function(promise) { return [promise[0].data.albums, promise[1].data.artists]; })
    .subscribe(function(result) {
        $scope.albums = result[0].slice(0, 5);
        $scope.artists = result[1].slice(0, 5);
        $scope.music = $scope.albums.concat($scope.artists);
    });

$scope.selectMusic = function(item) {
    console.log('music selected!', item);
    $scope.term = item.name;
};

$scope.imageSource = function(item) {
    return item.images['medium'];
};

$scope.hasAlbums = function() {
    return $scope.albums.length > 0;
};

$scope.hasArtists = function() {
    return $scope.artists.length > 0;
};

}]);
```

Comment: See the status, You are getting __404__, the API path is not correct

Comment: how to correct the API path ? please help me.

Comment: You need to show us the API code

Comment: i use rx.coincidence.js, rx.time.js, and rx.js for that. which one you want to see ? Also update te controller code.

Answer (score 1):

404, Status showing , that means client side error. Your API Path is not correct

Answer (score 1):

You can not run an AngularJS application directly from file system, if it uses http service. that's why it is giving CORS error. since you are trying fire an http request from file protocol.
To use a $http service you need a server. To test it locally you can install wamp/xampp server on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing cross region request error this error comes when your web application is in difference server and web api is on different api

Let say you web is hosted at : 192.168.0.1

and you are request api at     192.168.0.65

make sure both web and api on same server if not then cross region request is allowed

Answer (score 0):

So there seems to be 2 issues, as see from the screenshot provided:

- Cross-origin can not load file://
- status 404

For first problem, there are a number of threads already dealing with Cross Origin Request or CORS as it is used in general terms. You can have a look at some of those threads, like:

- [XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)
- [AngularJS Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes)
- [XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681965/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)

So, basically this means it displaying the error because you are directly trying to run the file instead it should be something like: http://localhost:8080/index.html or something of that sort.

A simple fix would be: deploy it to your web server locally or remote. 
A bit more complex would be: 
* install http-server and
* run the http server in your app directory

```
npm install -g http-server
```

once its installed, do :

```
cd <YOUR_APP_LOCATION>
http-server 
#OR
http-server -p 9090 -a 0.0.0.0 #this will start the webserver on port 9090
```

you can now open the url: http://localhost:8080/ OR http://127.0.0.1:9090/ and these CORS errors should be gone.

**Status 404 ** Problem
It looks the path specified in factory is not correct:

```
return $http.get('/api/album', { params: { q: term } });
```

Can you check your path and correct that in your factory? This should the problem for you.