# XMLHttpRequestObject.send does not send the data

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am running a wamp server from which I am developing a webpage. 
4 months ago, everything was working. However, now when I run the page, the `XMLHttpRequestObject.send("data=" + data);`
does not send the data.

Running the chrome debugger, I got the message:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. 
Failed to load: 'file:///C:/wamp/www/hello.php'.
```

Going through this post:
[XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)

a solution would be to run a local server.
 However, is there a way of doing this by only using WAMP?

Comment: WAMP IS a local server...?

Comment: Yes it is, but it still gives me the error.

Comment: I have tried restarting all the services, and Apache, php and MySQL are all up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit about what you're doing wrong--you need to specify a URL to send the request to that uses one of the mentioned protocols:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/hello.php', true);
xhr.send('data=' + data);
```

You can't point to `C:\wamp\www\hello.php`, because that's not where Apache is serving it from.  If you're using the default configuration, you probably want to use the URL `http://localhost/hello.php`.

As for running a local server, that's what the 'A' in 'WAMP' is.  Apache is a web server, which you can use to serve scripts and resources, e.g. a PHP script that is able to parse the data that you POSTed from your XHR request.

It's also worth mentioning that simply sending strings is not always the best way to send data to a server.  Depending on what you're sending, you might consider using the `FormData` or `Blob` objects in the `xhr.send()` call.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thank you very much. Earlier I was pointing it to C:\wamp\www\hello.php and it worked. But I guess chrome had a security update and this changed.
Thanks!