# 'Access is denied' error for HTTP get request in Adobe Air App using IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, webview, air, xmlhttprequest

I have an angularjs application that runs in a webview that is meant for a Windows Surface device (I am also using IE 11 instead of Adobe AIR webkit).

I want to load a local XML file from the app and I am using `$http.get()` for that.

The request is rejected with an `Access is denied` message.

I have tried using jQuery, Ajax and even `XMLHttpRequest(); / XDomainRequest()`but all throw the same error.

Looks like IE has cross domain issues for HTTP requests.

The HTTP get requests works well even on Mobile devices but is a real pain on IE :(

Is there any way to programmatically circumvent the additional security imposed by IE?

Your inputs are much appreciated.

Comment: I finally got around this issue by starting a HTTP server via Adobe Air sockets and hosting my local XML on it. So by calling a $http.get() in javascript with a url: `http://localhost:<port> /localFile.xml` I was able to get past the cross domain restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by starting a local http server and hosting my xml files on it. This way the http get request had a url of the form `http://localhost:<port>/myLocalFile.xml` and got around the cross domain issues. This worked perfectly for me!

Thanks to the contributors of the links below - your suggestions helped me!
http://answers.playcanvas.com/questions/833/cannot-load-model-due-to-cross-origin-request-being-blocked

[XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)