# How to convert a single page webapp into an offline format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I created a single page application using AngularJS. Is there a way to automatically convert it to an offline format like pdf or chm? The website contains multimedia content such as webms and ideally those should be preserved. Although having a single file (like a chm), would be preferable it would be sufficient to be able to view the contents of the website locally without having to use a web server.

Solutions like [saving webpage as MHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML#Google_Chrome), [HTML Help Workshop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138) and [WEB to CHM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/web2chm/) don't generate useful output. Allowing users to download the website and open the files directly doesn't work because of this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht).

Comment: What do you mean by "don't generate useful output" ?

Comment: I would look onto the offline web apps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Offline This is a way to get the page to save upon first online sessision, and then reuse the downloaded data