# Basic dimple.js Line Chart Issue - Loading data

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I am trying to load in data into a dimple.js line chart, but I am new to JavaScript and I am having trouble plotting a basic line chart.  I have a column for Watts and a column for Time.  How do I plot this in dimple.js?

My file contains a column for Time and a column for Watts.

I think there may be an issue on my line with:
*data = dimple.filterData(data, "Watts", []);*?

```
<html>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script src="dimple/js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dimple/js/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.csv("TESTFILE.txt", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      data = dimple.filterData(data, "Watts", []);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Time");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Watts");
      var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
      myChart.draw();
      });
  </script>
</div>
</html>
```

My current output is shown below:
[image]

[image: A screen capture of my data set]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
data = dimple.filterData(data, "Watts", []);
```

It's not needed and will delete everything in your data.  filterData removes all elements where the passed field's value is not in the array so an empty array will always remove all data.  It's only required if you want to filter your data, without it all data will be removed.

It sounds like you might have tried this so if it still doesn't work then there may be a further problem, please post a couple of rows from your data.

Comment: Hi John, I've added a photo of my data set.

Comment: I assume it's still not working once that line is removed.  It looks like your dataset is tsv not csv in which case use `d3.tsv` to get the data.

Comment: John, I tried `d3.tsv` but still, nothing showed up.  I inspected the element, and received the following errors:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users//Documents/Redacted/www/1382306R.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

and: Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

Comment: I found my issue.  Chrome is not allowing Cross Origin Requests.  I downloaded Firefox, ran the code in Firefox, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with my code.  I referred to this exchange to solve my problem.

I ended up downloading Firefox, running my code from Notepad++, and it worked perfectly.

[XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)