# Ajax is failing to get the content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am new to the `ajax`. This is the simple code i am trying to compile.
I dont know why it is not able to get the contents of the file.

Here is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"text.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }}).fail( function() {
                alert('Failed to get the content');
        });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Ajax</h2></div>

<button>Get Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

please someone tell me where i am going wrong.

Thnaks in advance.

**UPDATE** :-
After some trial and error and i got the desired result.
I missed out declaration of datatype that is `dataType:"text"` 
Now code is working perfectly.

Comment: is `text.txt` a URL?

Comment: You need to fully describe your problem. Does the fail function run? Are there errors in the Console of your developer tools? Can you see the request and response in the Network tab of your developer tools?

Comment: it is failing..and giving alert message

Comment: Change your fail to `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(textStatus,errorThrown)})`

Comment: change the URL to full absolute URL: `http://example.com/path/text.xml` and also test if that URL works in your browser

Comment: @abhishek — And what errors do you get?

Comment: 10 to 1 says [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht) is a duplicate

Comment: @mplungjan — I can't see any way that that would help unless the server was sending `Content-Type: application/json` for `.txt` files and the file didn't contain JSON … but that isn't likely.

Comment: in console it is showing the syntax error

Comment: @abhishek — Which syntax error?

Comment: it is indicating error to text.txt file

Comment: so console.log the actual arguments. `.fail( function() { console.log(arguments); })` and see what the error message is actually saying.

Comment: it is showing error like ` Error: Invalid XML`

Comment: So stop wasting our time and post all information including the file in question

Answer (score 0):

Where is your file is located? Make sure you have text.txt file in the same location as your html page.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers, Instead ANSWER the question with a valid answer to earn enough rep to comment

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly if file containing jquery code and text.txt file both are in same folder.

Comment: yeah both are in same folder

Answer (score -1):

Try error handling like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "text.txt",
      success: function(result) {

        $("#div1").html(result);

      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

instead of using `fail`