# how to run an external php file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

i want to know what is wrong with this code,I want to run an external program through php

```
function thisfunction(){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET","plm.php",true);
    x.send();
    return false;
}
```

this is my php file

```
<?php
function _exec($cmd) 
{ 
   $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); 
   $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0,false); 
   echo $cmd;
   return $oExec == 0 ? true : false; 
}_exec("mspaint.exe");
?>
```

Comment: Did you execute `thisfunction()`? What is the result?

Comment: What makes you think there *is* anything wrong with the code?  Is there some indication of a problem that you've neglected to describe?

Comment: what are you expecting to happen? paintbrush magically shows up in the user's browser?

Comment: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: And yes that i what i want to do . open an external program through php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to enable CORS.

From http://enable-cors.org/:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a specification that enables truly open access across domain-boundaries. If you serve public content, please consider using CORS to open it up for universal JavaScript/browser access.

Also read the following thread: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)

Comment: Now this i what i get  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Load jQuery: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Read more at http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined.html