# Why CORS issue is occurring while running Routing in Chrome and not in Firefox?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, routes, cors

Following the tutorial provided [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp) for routing in AngularJS, I am trying to run the same in my local.

I have the index.html as

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#red">Red</a>
<a href="#green">Green</a>
<a href="#blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### main.htm

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
This is main
</body>
</html>
```

### red.htm

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
This is red
</body>
</html>
```

And so for green.htm and blue.htm

When I run in Firefox, it works as expected - output below

[image]

But the same when I open in Chrome, the result is

[image]

What I need to do for resolving this CORS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without any issues on chrome for me. Here is the link to the working Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dyaY1CBvay8VXIZ2blTx?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
     .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
    templateUrl : "blue.html"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>
    <a href="#green">Green</a>
    <a href="#blue">Blue</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: even the article link I posted works too in chrome. But when I did the same  in my local, it's working fine in FF but not in  Chrome

Comment: Please post the exact code from your local as it will help to debug it.

Comment: What IDE are you using? I tried your code on Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013 and it is working fine on Chrome.  There is another similar post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht