# XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(0)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have this ajax request

```
var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
var urlAdd = '{{ route('postSocialWorker') }}';

$("#save").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:  urlAdd,
        data:{
            'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email': $('input[email=email]').val(),
            'store_id': $("select['name=store_id']").val(),
            _token: token
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if ((data.errors)) {
                $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.error').text(data.errors.name);
            }
            else {
                $('.error').addClass('hidden');
                $('#table').append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
            }
        },
    });
```

and this is my controller

```
public function addSocialWorker(Request $request)
{
   $rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|alpha_num',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'store_id' => 'required|numeric'
    );

   $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
   if ($validator->fails())
    return Response::json(array(
        'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ));
else {
    $data = new User();
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->email = $request->email;
    $data->status = 1;
    $data->role_id = 2;
    $data->store_id= $request->store_id;
    $data->save();
    return response()->json($data);
}

}
```

but i get this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(0). Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Any ideas? i'm using laravel

Comment: I think you meant to have `url: urlAdd`, not `url: 'urlAdd'`. Also, jQuery definitely does not use a `_token` AJAX config property so not sure what that's doing there

Comment: Still getting an error

Comment: You can prefer this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)

Comment: Please update the code in your question. @PramodPatil I highly doubt it's a CORS error. OP appears to be attempting to use a local Laravel route URL

Comment: @A.Sand Could you please update your code as per above suggestion given

Comment: What do you want me to provide?

Comment: If you tried the suggestion from the first comment, update your question to reflect the current state of your code. If the error message has changed, please provide the new one

Comment: So what should i put in the token? field?

Comment: Should i remove it?

Comment: @A.Sand sorry, your initial formatting made it look like you were passing a `_token` config property. I've fixed the formatting in your question to make it clearer. You should definitely be using `url: urlAdd` instead of `url: 'urlAdd'` though

Comment: Already changed it sir

Comment: Can you use your browser's *"view-source"* option to see what value is assigned to your `urlAdd` variable?

Comment: Ah, just thought of something. Try `$('#save').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // and the rest })`. I have a feeling you have `href="javascript:void(0)"` somewhere and that's being used in the request

Comment: Thank you i just removed the javascrip:void(0) because I forgot that it's using jquery thanks