# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, http

I am creating an offline page flip book.

The javascript links off to a PDF if I am running the site on MAMP local server. But when I try and run the code without being on a local server (desktop) it fails to load the PDF with the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/pmdesign7imac/Downloads/wow_book_plugin%202/examples/pdf/pdf_example.pdf. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Is it possible to link to the file without being on a server?

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui,maximum-scale=2">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui,maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./wow_book/wow_book.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='book_container'>
        <div id="book"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/helper.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./wow_book/pdf.combined.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./wow_book/wow_book.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var bookOptions = {
                 height   : 500
                ,width    : 800
                // ,maxWidth : 800
                ,maxHeight : 600

                ,centeredWhenClosed : true
                ,hardcovers : true
                ,pageNumbers: false
                ,toolbar : "lastLeft, left, right, lastRight, toc, zoomin, zoomout, slideshow, flipsound, fullscreen, thumbnails, download"
                ,thumbnailsPosition : 'left'
                ,responsiveHandleWidth : 50

                ,container: window
                ,containerPadding: "20px"
                ,pdf: "pdf_example.pdf"

            $('#book').wowBook( bookOptions );

        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's because of the `Http` part in `XMLHttpRequest`. HTTP implies a network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)

Comment: Actually XMLHttpRequest doesn't have to be XML and doesn't have to be HTTP. But code running in a browser cannot, without special arrangements, access filestore in the local machine, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

run your website localhost on your local server not as html file opened

Comment: The whole reason for me running it through the html is that the file will be on a memory stick. It will not have any server. Is there a work around?

Comment: you can install local server like xampp or wamp https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Again, this is using a local server. I do not want to use a local server. It needs to run from a memory stick.

Comment: read this carefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht

Comment: I understand that I can run the file from a local server on the memory stick. But, I do not want the user to have to start the server up to view the html. They need to be able to just double click the html file. Is that possible?

Comment: Also if I install a local server and the person is on a PC instead of mac surely the server would need another form of server?

Comment: the local server is required for each PC which website will run on it