# How to play around same-origin policy without using server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, same-origin-policy

I am building small **offline** web app using HTML and JavaScript. CSV file is used to store data.

To read CSV (using jquery-csv library) file I use following code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var filepath = 'data.csv';
        var data_string = $.get(filepath);
    });

</script>
```

But I can't read it because of following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/Nimal/Desktop/javascript-csv/data.csv. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https

Then, I found many related articles from here.

1. ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)
2. [XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht)
3. [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

---

But I could not find a way to solve my problem. I don't want to use web server. How do I load that CSV file to get data without error(error mean same-origin policy issue)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode . Also, FireFox works with get XMLHttpRequests locally.

Comment: @Teemu I am going to give this app for a few persons... So It is not possible to chnage their computers setting

Comment: Just adding a command to a short-cut path is not quite a "computer setting". Anyway, it's your only change with Chrome, unless you want to write a plug-in. Notice also what I've said about FF.

Comment: Surprisingly MS Edge seems to allow local get XMLHttpRequests too.