# Load external script after page is done loading by using $(document).ready() and $.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

As the title says I want to load a script by having my **script** tag on the header of the website and not the bottom of it.

A short example/attempt of mine would be this:

**HTML** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $.getScript("./js/script.js");
        } );
    </script>
   </head>
<body>
    <p id="para">hey there waht's up</p>
<body>
</html>
```

External **JS** file:

```
$("#para").click( function () {
    $("#para").hide();
})
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea why? Am I chasing unicorns?

Comment: `<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $.getScript("./js/script.js");
        } );
    </script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes):

> If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags.

So move the code to a separate script tag.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
    $(document).ready( function () { $.getScript("./js/script.js"); } );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested but it still wont work. So just to test that I have no mistakes in the code somewhere I added the script import at the bottom of body section and it worked. Something else I might be missing?

Comment: `jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///home/deus/Projects/web/test_jquery/js/script.js?_=1554722417976' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

I guess $.getScript doesn't work for local files.

Comment: @DeusDeceit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht

Comment: Yup, when served through apache it works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191447/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-deus-deceit).