# JSHint worker in Ace editor is blocked on static HTML page

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, ace-editor, jshint

I tried loading [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io) from an HTML file on my computer (using `file:///` protocol) to edit JavaScript:

```
ace.edit("editor", {
    "mode": "ace/mode/javascript",
})
```

However, CSP blocks a worker used by JSHint (which Ace implements by default). The following error is logged to the console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:null/[...] (“worker-src”).
```

When I set `loadWorkerFromBlob` to `false`:

```
ace.config.set("loadWorkerFromBlob", false)
```

A different error was generated:

```
Security Error: Content at file:///[...]/index.html may not load data from file:///[...]/ace/worker-javascript.js.
```

I tried to bypass CSP with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">` but to no avail, and searching this problem yielded no results.

How can I use JSHint in Ace editor from a local HTML page?

Edit: Forgot to specify that this is only a problem with Firefox. The first example worked completely fine for me on Chromium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file://` URLs produce a `null` Origin, as you can see in your error message:

```
The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:null/[...]
```

Therefore CORS doesn't support local `file://` access, pls see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914071/cors-error-for-application-running-from-file-scheme/25914800#25914800) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879729/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-file-sample-txt-from-origin-null-blocked-by-c).
Also [Chrome doesn't let you load web workers when running scripts from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408510/chrome-cant-load-web-worker/23206866#23206866).

The links above copntains some workarounds, but I think the best way is to run a local server to load workers via network schemes (http://localhost/...).

Comment: Do you know if there are any workarounds for Firefox? Despite what these links said, this problem strangely only occurs when I use Firefox and not Chromium.

Comment: Mozilla refers to a security policies and [recommends](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/simple-sync-worker-demo-local-debug-problem/54664) to run local web server.