# Loading HTML onto div of another HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I know this has been asked multiple times but I can't figure out why this won't work for me. Trust me, I've done research but I still can't see what's wrong with this. I'm also a complete noob at html and javascript/jquery so please be nice :)

My goal is to load a simple text from `text.html` onto `index.html`using jQuery.

This is my code as of right now

`index.html`

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#content').load("text.html");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

`text.html`

```
<body>
<p>Hello there!</p>
</body>
```

I have jQuery 3.4.1 in the same folder as these two files as well. When I drag index.html into Google Chrome I get a blank page. Of course, if I had any text in `index.html` it did show up when I loaded the html.

I'd also like to mention that I'm using `<div>` because I'm trying to do the same thing on another project by loading a div onto an html, so I'm seeing if even this small code would work, but sadly it's not. I've changed `<div>` in `index.html` into `<p>` and it made no difference.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: My goal is to have "hello there!" display. When I drag `index.html` into my web browser to preview what my output should look like, "Hello there!" does not display - instead, I get a blank page. I've tested `index.html` to have some other text in it, and it displays perfectly fine. The problem is that code from `text.html` doesn't seem to display.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work?" What errors are you getting?

Comment: The basic code shown should work if paths to jQuery.js and text.html are correct relative to your index.html page. Also assumes you are not running this in `file://` protocol. `load()` will not work in `file://`

Comment: i test your code , its work to me , please explain what happend to your code when run it ?

Comment: When you just drag the file into chrome you are opening it in `file://` protocol. Will need to run a localhost server to use ajax. Lots of ways to easily set up a localhost server

Comment: Can you move your script below the body tag. To be sure that your script will run after the html has loaded.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578692/7874305