# Is there any way to use function like <?php include> in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

i'm working on new `phonegap` application and the backend of my app written with `php`
i have a many page in my app and the `header` section in all of the page is same,
in the php we using `<?php include="header">` to call the header,
 is there any way in `phonegap` or `javascript` to doing like so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible, because PHP is a server-sided language. You need to realize your client logic with JavaScript. For implementing multiple html pages with jQuery (a JS library), take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/common-header-and-footer-include-multiple-html-pages).

Moreover, you can write a web service with PHP and access it via the `ajax`-object in JS.