# including html files with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to include an .html file into another page using javascript or jQuery, for example a header and a footer file, as these remain the same throughout whole project. The issue I can see with using jQuery is that it will probably be inside one of such files, hence not loaded before it is used, so I would assume javascript would be a better choice.

If such method exists will it cache loaded / included files as well?

Ideal solution would not require usage of containers to load data into, but instead include a file as is in place where include code is specified.

EDIT: As to some suggestions .load method can be used, but lets say I needed to load  tag and its contents like css files, some javascript etc wich is used on whole pages, it seems incorrect to load it into a div, is there a way to achieve it? Is usage of $(document).load("header") a possible solution?

Comment: @Andy What if I want to include whole header so with <header> tag and all its contents? So I don't have to specify css files on every page, etc.. I can see issue with dynamic page titles with this approach, but for a sake of an example lets ignore it

Comment: @Ilja You can have only one `head` element per page, unless you want to use `iframe`s... Just load the stuff you need to the `head` of the actual page.

Comment: I would look at templating engines such as angular or doT.js, might make your job a little bit easier. Here is a site that might help you [find one](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a document looking like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200 ) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML += ajax.responseText;
        }
    }

    ajax.open("GET", "head.html", true);
    ajax.send();

    ajax2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( ajax2.readyState == 4 && ajax2.status == 200 ) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = ajax2.responseText;
        }
    }

    ajax2.open("GET", "body.html", true);
    ajax2.send();

</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
```

HTML would be:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/common-header-and-footer-include-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: Yea, This is method used in comment left by Andy, but say if I wanted to load it with whole <head> tag and its content, so css files etc, so I will not have to define them on every page?

Comment: is it possible to achieve something like that through $(document).load("header.html") ? But in this case it will have to be a javascript method as we don't have jQUery loaded yet.