# Need Help to load a html page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am newly designing the web page using CSS,HTML and Jquery.
I have designed  the page having only the header part. That header page i want to use in different pages.I have referred [Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-include-multiple-html-pages) ,but still it is not working .

I have two html files.
header.html which is working fine.Check it  jsfiddle.net/Binay_Kumar/3xqwh/2/

And in my second page header1.html ,i want to link that header.html and some other content of the second page.

**Coding**

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
      <link href="../CSS/stylenew.css"type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
      <div id="header">
       <div id="codeoverheader">
         X SERVICES PVT. LTD.   </div> 
        <div id="codeoverheader1">
          Home|Logout
        </div>
       </div>   
         <div id="header1"></div>
        <div id="header2"></div>
         <div id="backgroundofmenu1"> <!--I have changed as backgroundofmenu1 instead of backgroungofmenu-->
         </div>
         <div id="menu1">
           <a href="secondpage1.html" style="text-decoration:none" id="menucolor" >My HomePage</a></div>
         <div id="menu1line1"> <!--i have changed from 1 to 11-->
        | </div>     
        <div id="menu2">
         <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" id="menucolor" class="Mydata">My Data</a></div>
       <div id="menu2line2"><!--i have changed from 2 to 21-->
         |</div>           
       <div id="menu3">
        <a href="secondpage2.html" style="text-decoration:none" id="menucolor">Policies And Info</a></div>
        <div id="menu3line3"><!--i have changed from 1 to 31-->
         | </div>  
       <div id="menu4">
        <a href="secondpage3.html" style="text-decoration:none" id="menucolor">Help</a>    </div>
  </head>
```

It is working fine.

header1.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link href="../CSS/stylenew.css"type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script> 
           $(document).ready(function(){
             $(function(){
               $("#headerpage").load("header.html"); 
             });
         });
       </script>
     </head>
  <body>
     <div id="headerpage"></div>
       <div id="hello">
          hello
      </div>
</body>
```

Some problem is there in this page.

stylenew.css

```
 #header{ 
   position:absolute; 
   top:0;  
   left:0; 
   width:100%; 
   height:header-<length>; 
   height:17%;
   background-color:#004080;
       } 
  #header1{
   position:absolute; 
   top:15%; 
   left:0; 
   width:100%; 
   height:2%;
   background-color:#9ABD2B;  <!-- #CCFF33 first it was there -->
     }
  #hello{
     left:300px;
     top:200px;
     position:absolute;
     font-size:18px;
    }
```

Anyway CSS is working fine ,as it is so lengthy ,so i am not sharing.

**The problem is while running the header1.html it is displaying only hello** but i am expecting the header.html page content as well as hello.

Can anyone tell what is the mistake i have done ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Binay_Kumar/3xqwh/2/  (header is working )fine please check it.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why i got downvote for this question ? ok no pbm .I am struggling from last 2 days to solve this problem ?

Comment: What does your JavaScript error console say?

Comment: What does the Net tab in your Developer tools say? Is the request for the header being made? Is the response what you expect?

Comment: no error only hello is coming while running the header1.html

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /D:/A%20Product%20Ispl%20New/HTML/header1.html:10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the error, the problem appears to be that jQuery isn't loading.  It's probably because you are working locally.  Change the src for your script tag that loads jQuery to include the http like this:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks @jme11 for helping me.I have done what you told.Before i was getting 2 errors now i am getting one error.i.e XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/A%20Product%20Ispl%20New/HTML/header.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Again, it's because you're working locally and not testing on a server.  AJAX (that load method that you're calling) requires a server.  So either test on an external server or install a local server for testing.  MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/) for Mac is free and fairly simple to set up, or if you're using Windows, you can try WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/).  There are tons of tutorials on installing/configuring these on YouTube.

Comment: To load  a html file ,i have to install  server.Actually first time i am doing so only i am asking don't feel bad.

Comment: Yes, you will need a server for AJAX calls. jQuery methods like: $.ajax(), $.get(), load(), post() are all a form of AJAX.

Comment: You can just test your files on the server where you intend to host it , if you're not comfortable installing a server.  But, this will eventually get tiresome.  Those two options I suggested aren't really that difficult to get installed and running (and I'd even say, easy if you are on a MAC).

Comment: Then you'll need to use something other than MAMP.  That only works on MAC OS.  You can try WAMP instead: http://www.wampserver.com/.  I don't have a lot of experience with it, but as I said, there are lots of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

Your relative URI to jQuery is wrong because you are using a `file` URI. You could fix *that* by using an absolute URI (which starts with `http` or `https`, but then you will run into Same Origin Policy issues for using Ajax on local files.

Install a web server on your development machine so you're testing in a web-like environment.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Yes after doing that 1 error reduced but still one error is there XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/A%20Product%20Ispl%20New/HTML/header.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. /D:/A%20Product%20Ispl%20New/HTML/header1.html:1

Comment: So will you tell me what to do with the server only i have to install or any settings i have to do.

Comment: You have to load the document through it (by visiting `http://localhost/something/something`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here exactly, but it seems that you want to load the contents of header.html into header1.html. If this is the case, then header.html should **not** contain the  and  tags, since that would result into something like.

Furthermore, you don't have appropriate closing tags in multiple positions (e.g.  in header.html and header1.html).

So if you want to make something  like this work, do something like this:

header.html

```
<div>
    ...Your header contents here...
</div>
```

my_page.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $('#my-header').load('header.html');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my-header">
            ... Your header will be inserted here by jQuery
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So in this example, header.html only contains some HTML markup (no HTML, HEAD and BODY tags!) and it is included by my_page.html. I hope this makes things clear for you.

I suppose you got downvoted because it seems you mainly just copy pasted some code into your own project without really understanding what's going on. Also, you should post your code here as clean as possible. So if something doesn't work, just try and make a minimal example out of it, so people on SO don't have to scan through all the irrelevant parts.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation . But i didn't copy and paste the code ,i have referred that ,everything i have designed by my own only.

Comment: I did not say that you did, I am only saying that it seemed like it, since your post is a bit messy. I am just giving some hints on why I thought your question might have received a downvote, that's all.