# How to activate link in another html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-include-multiple-html-pages) thread I carried out my header into the individual html file

header.html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation" style="height: auto;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/page1.html">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page2.html">Page2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and included it in my index.html.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#navbar-header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="navbar-header"></div>
```

My question is, how to apply 'active' class on selected page (page1 and page2)?

```
<li class="active"><a href="/page1.html">Equator Server</a></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean with activate? Do they not work at all or?

Comment: Do you want to apply activate class on selected page

Comment: This is so unclear i can't even read the last sentence. What is this supposed to mean ? "Activate" ?

Comment: Yogesh is right, my question is how to apply activate class on selected page?

Comment: Do you have to use active class? What if you get the desired styling results without using the 'active' class in your html. If yes, I can post the answer.

Comment: Yes, I need just styling results while one of the page has been chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use jQuery's .addClass(), using specific class in the html, 
for example

HTML-file to add menu

```
<div class="class1" id="navbar-header"></div>
```

separate file with header

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($( "#navbar-header" ).hasClass( "class1" )) {
            $("#id-to-add").addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a jQuery Click() event on target element by adding a click event listener on source element (an element which should activate a link on another html).

```
$('.icon-bar-1').on('click', function(){
  $('.page-1').click(function(){/* code to perform on targetted click listener */});
});
```

Comment: Andrejs, thank you for your answer could you please make it clear, is it necessary to put a class inside <li> tag?

<li class="page-1"><a href="/page1.html">Page1</a></li>.

Or how is that works?