# Is there a way for include a <script> or <link> in all pages one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, import

For example in a web application/website I have n... pages, and I must write always in all pages the information of imports css and javascript, is there a way for import this only in the index.html and apply it all pages?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618893/put-html-head-in-another-file

Comment: @Tudor Are you okay with using jQuery? Your question doesn't have the `jquery` tag, as it stands.

Comment: @AlexW yes I am... now I add it now!

Comment: You can also take a look at server-side includes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP installed on the server you can require or include parts of pages.

then you have for example 2 files
- index.php
- header.php

**Header.php**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js">
</head>
```

etc...

and in index.php you can include this part of the page like:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
   include('header.php');
?>
// rest of page
<body>
 Etc...
```

Comment: Yes..., this is best solution for my project in php. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with JavaScript and jQuery. Create function like:

```
function importCSS(){
var import = document.createElement('link');
i=0;
while(i<importData.length){
import.href=importData[i];
import.rel="stylesheet"
document.head.appendChild(import)
i++;
}
importData=["css1.css","css2.css",..."cssN.css"];
}
```

And then just call importCSS() in your file like:

```
$(document).ready(importCSS());
```

Otherwise I would use a language like PHP to pull the style information from a file or database.