# Can I link to a <head> tag in a separate file to avoid having to change them all if I make a change?

Tags: css, html

I want to create a website, where instead of copying the `<head>` tag to each new page. I want to put it in its own file just reference it in each page.

I tried using `<object data="head.html">`, with head.html having a link to style.css. But instead of changing the entire body background color to red, it just made a small red rectangle.

### **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <object data="head.html"></object>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### **style.css**

```
body{
    background-color:red;    
}
```

### **head.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
</html
```

I expected it to make the entire page red with the word "Hello" in it, but it made a small red rectangle with "Hello" under the rectangle.

**I see that other question, however I'm not very experienced with using java script in web pages.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put HTML head in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618893/put-html-head-in-another-file)

Comment: What language you are using for web. Templates are mostly used for this purpose, not only for css, you can use templates for fixed headers or footers for every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is how to involve a certain html code from outside and use it twice or more ... Like using a paritcular design in all the web pages in the project folder.
Try this..

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/imports/stuff.html">
</head>
```

If you are using PHP then it is the best way to include HTML code..

```
include_once('stuff.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a programming language like PHP where you can include another file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the height of your html and body tags are just as large as it's contents. Try setting this in your CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

That will make it expand to be the browser windows size.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't change anything.