# How do I use the same header and footer for all of my pages

Tags: html

I am creating a new page and have developed a header which includes a logo on the left, a div on the right which contains a username and password label and input, and a login button:
Under that is a div which is empty except for a border giving it a line.
Under that is a 1 row, 5 column table with the menu.

I would like for that to be on every page that I write, but centralized so that any changes that I make only need to be changed in one place. I think it is possible in php, but I don't know how to write php. Is there a way to do it in html?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: You are correct. I had not seen that one. It had some useful information on it though the simplicity of the response from you below was more concise and simple. Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do it using PHP, you need to create the code in separate files. `header.html` and `footer.html`

Use this below code in `filename.php`

```
<?php include('header.html'); ?>

/* Rest of the body content */

<?php include('footer.html'); ?>
```