# Header & Footer template with positive SEO implications & no PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, footer

We would like to create HTML pages on our ecommerce website that is hosted by Network Solutions. Each of these pages will need to have our header/menu and footer that will change from time to time. Unfortunately our platform doesn't have PHP installed on its servers and I am not able to upload PHP files to the file manager.

What is my the best option for having a dynamic header? We are looking to have an SEO friendly solution if possible, and I'm not sure of a way to use jQuery or Javascript while also being SEO friendly and loading all of the HTML code on the same page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: I decided to create a new post because I believe those solutions have negative implications on SEO or require PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose between not using PHP and SEO-friendly code. Because on-page SEO is depended on the code in the HTML and can't take into account dynamically inserted/generated code. And the latter is necessary if you don't want to use PHP (or some other server-side language) to insert code.

So, I'm afraid it isn't possible..