# Boostrap left menu, Header footer in separate unique file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

after have read tons of different article on the web

i'm looking on a simple way to have in bootstrap my left menu, header and footer on a separate and unique file
this is to prevent having to re-write anythings on each different pages of my application (i'm using a boostrap admin template)

thanks for your advices

Comment: What's holding you from doing that? You can create a separate file for the menu/footer/header and add them dynamically to the page through jquery. Or, even better you could use AngularJS to make the menu/footer/header separate templates.

Comment: how can in include them in my boostrap page?

Comment: Are you using only html css and javascript? Are you using jQuery or some other framework?

Comment: HTML/CSS javascript jquery and boostrap

Comment: Have you read this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages

Comment: thanks after lot of try, i finally use $(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after lots of tries, I use:

```
 $(function(){   $("#header").load("header.html");   
 $("#footer").load("footer.html");  });
```

Don't know why, it doesn't work 100% on a local file, but it's ok on the web site.