# How to manage several html nav bars from one single area in order to avoid going to each html page and changing the nav bar link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am responsible for managing several `.html` pages which follows a rather simple bootstrap template that includes a nav bar. The problem is, as I continue to build out more pages, often times I am going back to redo the nav bar on each individual `.html` page.

While very time-consuming, I was under the impression when I learned about front-end markup that there wasn't another way to go about managing your nav bar.

I tried searching for this thread before asking a question, but I wasn't able to find one that hit close to home for me.

I am curious, is there a way to manage the nav bar for all your html pages from a single point or destination, without having to go back into each individual `.html` page and add the necessary changes? It would be nice if someone could recommend a vanilla html/css/js solution, if not I am open to any recommendations for any frameworks that may cater to this problem.

Comment: I haven't used basic html in a while, but in things like `ejs` `pug` `mustache` you can make a header part of an html page and just include it in each of your other html pages. I do not know if using basic js and html give you that functionality, but as I said it has been a while since I used those to alone and that was it.

Comment: This sort of question won't solicit quality answers because there are too many options; none is 'right' or objectively better.  You could use JavaScript to insert the Nav element on each page, you could use server-side includes (SHTML), or any numerous other options that allow your HTML pages to be output from templates.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: you have to add your code to let us better understand what you are doing. create your header as a separate file and query it... I use Ajax to call and insert elements like that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the script tag in `index.html` (or other page you want to use it) like this:

```
<script style="text/javascript" src="navLoader.js"></script>
```

Delete all the navbar code from `index.html` (or other pages that will use the navbar) and replaced with:

```
<div class="navbar-frame"></div>
```

Create a `navbar.html` file with all the navbar code:

```
<!--Header bar!-->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Your Stuff</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="background-header"><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="background-header"><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle background-header" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header dropdown-divisor">Java</li> 
                <li class="background-header"><a href="/TEXTLAND/Textlandrpg.html">TEXTLAND textual RPG</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header dropdown-divisor">HTML5 & Javascript</li>
                <li class="background-header"><a href="#">Another test</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header dropdown-divisor">HTML/CSS</li>
                <li class="background-header"><a href="/CSSolarSystem/SolarSystemHTMLCSS.html">CSSolar System</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="background-header">
                <a href="#">Contact
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="background-header"><a href="#">Leave a comment</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

and then create a `navLoader.js` file with this .load method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navbar-frame").load("navbar.html");
});
```

Every time the page is fully loaded, it will go to `navLoader.js` get the `navbar.html` and load it inside the `.navbar-frame div`.  Now, if you need to change something in the navbar, just change the `navbar.html` file.
 And of course, change the `li` tags as you need, this is just an example.
(using jQuery)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Does jQuery CDN have to exist in both `index.html` and `navbar.html`? I want to get your example up and running so I tried using jQuery CDN 3.2.1 this one `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` but it does not work.

Comment: If the Navbar.html doesn't use any kind of javascript code, only pure html, so it doesn't need the jQuery call. You will need it only in every page that loads the navbar. don't forget that the call for jQuery must happen always before any other script.

Comment: It was brought to my attention from someone helping me out that there were some errors in your code, such as using `class` instead of `id` for `index.html` and the `<script>` that references the `script.js` has `res` instead of `src`. I think I got it to work, thank you!