# Include header in multiple htm files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a nodeJs application in which I am serving html files on request. I have started working with Html recently. I want to create multiple html files but want to include the similar **header.html** in those all multiple html file. I have read different articles such as:
[Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages). Also I have tried to use Html5 **import** statement but nothing is working. Is there any other way to do this with Html5 or with javascript or jquery. my code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){ $("head").load("header.html") });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="frontpage"/>
<script src="./bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

whereas my header.html is:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycssfile.css"/>
<title>My application</title>
```

But it is not working! is there any way to make it working?

The error I am getting is :

GET http://localhost:3000/header.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Remove a colon in the url, try this: http://localhost/header.html

Comment: @TigerTV.ru it gives the error not found

Comment: Does your web server work on port 3000?

Comment: `$(function(){ $("head").load("/header.html") })`

Comment: @Developer You should use JADE Template engine instead of loading header and footer this way.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru yes

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly not working

Comment: If you get the 404 error than it means that web server can't find the `header.html` in the `web` directory of `localhost`. What would be if you open this link http://localhost:3000/ or http://localhost/index.html?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/index.html

Comment: @TigerTV.ru it also give not found 404 error.

Comment: It means you put you files in another directory. You need to find out where your web directory is.

Comment: @TigerTV I am using it like this res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/../../views/" + "index" + ".html")) on the node server

Comment: Maybe path is not forming correctly, find the value of `__dirname + "/../../views/" + "index" + ".html"`

Comment: root directory you can set this way `res.sendFile('../public/index.html', {root: __dirname});`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru everythin is working good when I run it from backend but if I copy paste your localhost:3000/index.html it say No file found. I have also tried to debug __dirname + "/../../views/" + "index" + ".html" and place the value in the browser with localhost;3000 still it is giving error

Comment: Do I have to include header in webpack?