# How do I get a HTML document to refer to the "header" and "footer" elements in other HTML documents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whilst I'm coding I'd like to be able to see the HTML I've created, for example, I have a `index.html` which refers to a header navigation file.

Using `jQuery`, I can get this to work on the server side but I want it to work locally as well but I heard current versions of browsers have security which prevents it from working with local files.

Does anyone know of a browser or a setting or an alternative that will allow the reuse of HTML linkages to work locally as well as on the server side?

The code below (obtained from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712605/10415695)) only works on the server side.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#header").load("header.html"); 
      $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <!-- remaining section -->
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Surely there's a better way that'll allow me to see my `<header />` and `<footer />` elements without having to deploy to the server after every update.

Sometimes I just want to test changes in navigation without deploying.

Comment: Meet [XAMPP](https://xampp.org), for example.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** It really depends on the language you want to use.

#### JavaScript:

The simplest way to create a static HTTP server is by using [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/):

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use("/", express.static("dist"));
app.listen(3000, function () {
  return console.log("Express: Listening on port 3000.");
});
```

Save that code in a `*.js` file, run it using `node filename.js` and visit [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000) in your web browser.

If you don't have express installed, run the following command in your terminal:

```
npm install -g express
```

**NOTE:** If you don't have `node` or `npm` installed you can install them by following the download instructions [on the project's official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

#### Python(3):

The [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) comes a module called [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) which you can use to create a virtual host for your project.

First you'll have to `cd` into your project directory, like this:

```
cd ~/path/to/your/project
```

Then run the following command:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

When you're done, open your web browser and visit [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000).

If you'd like to change the port you can use the following command:

```
python3 -m http.server 7000
```

**Warning:** `http.server` is not recommended for production because it only implements basic security checks.

#### Python(3) Flask:

If you'd like to go all out and use back-end a web framework, you could create a [Flask app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) by saving the following code in a `*.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template("./path/to/your/template.html")

app.run(debug = True, port = 8000)
```

Then run the script using `python3 filename.py` and visit [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000) in your web browser.

If you don't have Flask installed you can install it via [Pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) using:

```
pip3 install flask
```

Or you can install it via the apt package manager (if you're on Ubuntu or Debian), like this:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
```

#### PHP:

If you're using PHP, you'll have to install a lamp server and the simplest way to install this is to use `tasksel`, like this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

I don't know what language or OS you're using (and to be honest I can't keep guessing) so instead of writing a detailed answer as to [how to install a LAMP server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04), I'll add a link instead, I'll also link a tutorial on [how to install a virtual host](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04/#virtual-hosts).

**INFO:** [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Good luck.