# How to include header/footer in a static website?

Tags: html, firebase

I'm building a serverless website (on Firebase) for the first time, and is there a way to include a block of html code (e.g. header/footer) across multiple different pages?

I'm used to using express or django where I can include a footer/header component so I don't have to duplicate code. Is there a way to do this for a pure html/css/js static site or do I need to duplicate header/footer html across all my pages?

Comment: This question is duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages

Comment: There's a way to solve this here I think, check it out:
[Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: Thank you all, will close the question