# Make common headers and footers for website with folders

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm wanting to create a website with common headers and footers for each webpage and am currently using the answer supplied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712605/10623723).

However, I have a website with a tree diagram similar to:

```
- index.html
- header.html
- footer.html
- folder
    - info.html
```

In my header and footer files, there are multiple (relative) links such as to image sources, other pages, etc, which means while they may work in index.html, if I try to load it into info.html, the links break.

Is there any way to change all links to look one folder back, etc, or would I have to use javascript to change the `src` property for every referenced image?

Comment: May I see your code?

Comment: If you use *root relative* paths you can avoid this issue also. A leading `/` tells browser to start at root of site. So if you have an `images` folder the path `/images/someImage.jpg` will work the same in your `folder/info.html` as it will in `index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the  `<base>` element to your info.html and make its `href` tallying the relative links of your header and footer markups.

For example, if your website is hosted in `http://example.com/foo` and your relative links are such as `./images/xyz.jpg`, the base element of the info.html would be like this:

```
<base href="http://example.com/foo">
```

The browser will compose the relative urls from there.

---

Another option is to configure your relative urls to pick up resources from the root.

In above configuration, instead of this:

```
<img src="./images/xyz.jpg">
```

...you can use

```
<img src="/foo/images/xyz.jpg">
```

So, wherever it is executed from, browsers will start the relative paths from the root.

The advantage is that this will enable easy local testing too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<base>` tag in your `info.html` file's `<head>` tag with a `href` attribute.

The `<base>` tag specifies the base URL and target for all relative URLs in a document.

The `<base>` tag must have either an href or a target attribute present, or both.

There can only be one single `<base`> element in a document, and it must be inside the `<head>` element.

You can find more in this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_base_test).

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element is for. You include it in the document and specify an href from which all relative links/urls are resolved.