# Joining Two different HTML file in single HTML file

Tags: html, css

I want to generate three pages in html
1.header
2.container 
3.footer
in different html pages
And last i want to integrate all 3 html page in single page as index.html.

Please tell me how will i do this??

Comment: What language/framework are you using to build the web page? Or, are you literally writing raw HTML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below method

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="content">
      Main Content
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script>
      $("#header").load("header.html");
      $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Would suggest you to go through the below links as well

1. [Common Header / Footer with static HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418503/common-header-footer-with-static-html)
2. [Make header and footer files to be included in multiple html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)

Comment: But how we write header.html and footer.html Is we write hole html, head, body  tag ???

Comment: it is not required to add the whole html along with all the html, head and body tags. only the required tags would do the job for you. as such you would have all those tags in your main html file.

Comment: It mean we have to write CSS and Script In main file ??

Comment: Yes. Include your CSS and JS script files in the main file and have only the code for header and footer in the respective html files.

Comment: OK thanks it is important for me thanks thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You can done this with angularjs easily using **ng-include** directive to learn about this follow below link.

[Combine multiple html](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp)

Comment: without angularjs how we use it??

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712605/6385066
**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can reuse the function for all your pages to include your header and footer.